# how do i extract different Field output data with abapy?

Tags: python, abaqus

In abaqus, I navigated to field output request and there I checked the box before 'E, total strain component' because it wasn't standard checked.
But after I try to access this information with the code:

```
odb.steps[ stepname ].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['E']
```

i get an error saying "keyerror: E"

Comment: nothing wrong to tell from that snippet.  Strain is available by default although of course it will not be there if there was some error and the job didnt even run.

Comment: `E` won't appear in certain types of analyses. Check if you have logarithmic strain available to you instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field output `E` will appear only when you have turned off nonlinear geometry. This is because its the engineering strain.
When `nlgeom=on` , abaqus will calculate logarithmic strain and you won't get `E` in the field output.

Answer (score 0):

For geometrically nonlinear analysis using element formulations that support finite strains, E is not available for output to the odb file, and LE (logarithmic strain) is the default strain measure.

Either way, you can request integration point outputs to the data, results, or odb file. See "Abaqus/Standard output variable identifiers" section. If you are running hyperfoam, hyperelastic, or user materials you may want to request directly the deformation gradient DG. With the DG field you then can calculate any approriate strain measure.